# What type of link I need to use if I want to promote my new website on my old website?

Tags: seo, google, penalty

What type of link I need to use if I want to promote my new website on my old website?
I can use simple clean link:

`<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit my new website with funny dog photos</a>`

or need be with `nofollow noopener`

`<a href="https://www.google.com" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">Visit my new website with funny dog photos</a>`

Comment: Why would you want to nofollow a link to your new website from your old website? Don't you want search engines to give link juice to your new site? Likewise, why set noopener?  Don't you trust your new website to not hack your old one? (Just use the clean link.)

Comment: I want use nofollow because i will later remove that link from website, and i not want for google after i remove kill my new website page rank

Answer (score 2):

While Google [can penalize "personal blog networks" that all link to each other](https://searchengineland.com/private-blog-networks-great-way-get-site-penalized-286489), it usually has to come with spammy, low quality and/or duplicate content for Google to really care. If you're just lightly promoting one upstanding, unique website from another, there's not much to worry about.